# How can I keep the rightmost instead of leftmost contents of a TD?

Tags: css, css-tables

I have a TD with contents often wider than the TD, a text-align of right, and an overflow-x of hidden. It is displaying the leftmost portion of its contents.

Let us say for the sake of argument that the cell content is "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", and the TD will show exactly six characters with a hidden overflow-x.

It is now showing "ABCDEF".

How can I show "UVWXYZ"?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `direction: rtl`.

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 70px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  direction: rtl;
  /*text-align: right;*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```